# Can't share Content Document with Salesforce object

Tags: contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

I have a Salesforce org with Salesforce CRM Content enabled but I can't share Content Document with Salesforce object. There are no Related Content related list in layout and I also can't create the link (between Salesforce object and Content Document) programmatically, I get "Unable for insert ContentDocumentLink for MyDocument.pdf.Error:Invalid sharing type I." which perfectly work on other environment. Is there any setting or permission missed?
The org is regular org, no Communitites.